# How do I force Gradle to run a task upon every build?

Tags: gradle, build, task

I’m using Gradle 2.7 on Mac Yosemite.  When building my WAR, assuming all the tests pass and assembly of the war is successful, I’d like to copy my WAR to my local `$CATALINA_HOME/wbeapps` directory.  So I have defined this in my `build.gradle` script:

```
task deployToTomcat(type: Copy) {
    from war.archivePath
    into "$System.env.CATALINA_HOME/webapps"
}

build.dependsOn deployToTomcat
```

When I run `gradle build` I can see that the task is run, but nothing appears in my `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` directory.  Here is the output:

```
davea$ gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:war UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:update
liquibase-plugin: Running the 'main' activity...
INFO 10/28/15 2:11 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 10/28/15 2:11 PM: liquibase: Reading from cbc_db.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 10/28/15 2:11 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Liquibase Update Successful
liquibase-plugin: Running the 'test' activity...
INFO 10/28/15 2:11 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 10/28/15 2:11 PM: liquibase: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 10/28/15 2:11 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Liquibase Update Successful
:testClasses
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:deployToTomcat UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE
```

Does “UP-TO-DATE” mean it was run?  How can I force the task to run?

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, I changed my task.  The WAR file gets copied to a folder named "null/webapps" in the same directory as my "build.gradle" file.  Here is the output

```
davea$ echo $CATALINA_HOME
/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.44
davea$ gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:war UP-TO-DATE
:deployToTomcat UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:update
liquibase-plugin: Running the 'main' activity...
INFO 10/29/15 9:09 AM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 10/29/15 9:09 AM: liquibase: Reading from cbc_db.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 10/29/15 9:09 AM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Liquibase Update Successful
liquibase-plugin: Running the 'test' activity...
INFO 10/29/15 9:09 AM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 10/29/15 9:09 AM: liquibase: Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 10/29/15 9:09 AM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Liquibase Update Successful
:testClasses
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.865 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to force task to be run. Instead please configure the tasks appropriately:

```
task deployToTomcat(type: Copy) {
    from war.outputs
    into "$System.env.CATALINA_HOME/webapps"
}

war.finalizedBy deployToTomcat
```

`archivePath` defines the path where war will be placed but to get the war you need to use task's `outputs` property.

`finalizedBy` runs given task always after the tasks it finalizes. In this particular case this guarantees that the artifact being built will be prepared.

`UP-TO-DATE` means that the task wasn't run. It had nothing to do.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed my task to reflect what you wrote.  However one thing I'm noticing in both cases (my try and your answer), the war gets copied to "null/webapps/myproject.war".  THis is strange because when I echo $CATALINA_HOME, it outputs a value.  I have included the output in an edit to my question.

Comment: @Dave, I'm sorry but CATALINA_HOME variable is referenced correctly. Something seems to be misconfigured. If you invoke mentioned tasks from IDE it might cause the problem - system env are not visible from IntelliJ IDEA. If you found my answer useful, please accept it.

Comment: I'm running "gradle build" in a terminal (bash shell).  Before I accept I want to solve the problem first -- maybe its something unique to my environment but if the variable echo's I figure it shoudl be recognized in my Gradle script.  I'll up-vote you, tho.

Comment: @Dave, what's your OS? I'm really sorry, but I've just tried with lots of env variables and it all works for me.

Comment: @Dave, please print all the env variables in gradle script with the following piece of code: `System.env.each { k, v -> println "$k=$v" }`. Is `CATALINA_HOME` present there? Also, how you set the env variable? Via any *profile* file or, by export statement? Remember that this env variable must be visible for JVM. Do you use gradle daemon?